# How to parse HH:mm into amount of minutes considering locale time separator?

Tags: java, time, java-8, locale, separator

I have an input string of 'HH:mm' format where time separator is according to locale settings (e.g. '10:45' for US or '10.45' for Italy). I need to convert it into amount of minutes.

Here is what I came up with:

```
String timeSeparator = getTimeSeparator(locale);
String[] duration = durationString.split(Pattern.quote(timeSeparator));
int minutes = Integer.valueOf(duration[0])*60 + Integer.valueOf(duration[1]);
```

`getTimeSeparator` method taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7612009/7753225

Is there any simpler way? For example using `java.time'.

Comment: you can remove the Integer.valueOf() as you are not even using an Integer, (and even then, it will be autoboxed). I think JodaTime had this option though. To get the number of minutes/seconds/whatever from a datetime

Comment: Why not just ignore the separator? `int minutes = Integer.parseInt(durationString.substring(0, 2)) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(durationString.substring(3))`

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.parse( 
    "PT" + 
    "10:45".replace( ":" , "M" )
           .replace( "-" , "M" )
           .replace( "." , "M" )
           .replace( "," , "M" )
    + "S" 
).toMinutes()
```

> "10:45" → PT10M45S → 10

## ISO 8601 format

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) standard defines a format for such spans of time not attached to the time line: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`

The `P` marks the beginning. The `T` separates any years-months-days from the hours-minutes-seconds. So an hour and a half is `PT1H30M`. Your example of ten minutes and forty-five seconds is `PT10M45S`.

Perform simple string manipulations to convert your input to this format.

```
String input = "10:45" ;
String inputStandardized = "PT" + 
    input.replace( ":" , "M" )
         .replace( "-" , "M" )
         .replace( "." , "M" )
         .replace( "," , "M" )
         + "S" ;
```

> PT10M45S

## `Duration`

Parse as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMinutes--). The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing and generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Duration duration = Duration.parse( inputStandardized );
```

> duration.toString(): PT10M45S

You can use the `Duration` object to do date-time math, passing to `plus` and `minus`. So you may not need the number of minutes as an integer number. But you can ask for total number of minutes in the duration.

```
long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
```

> 10

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/S8iRIF).

Tip: Using a clock-time format for a span of time is asking for trouble. The ambiguity leads to confusion and errors. I suggest using the standard ISO 8601 formats for durations as they are designed to be unambiguous, easy to read, and easy to parse.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you could use [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedTime-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) to obtain a locale-specific date-time formatter. Then you could use it to [parse the string into a `LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) and [extract the minute field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#getMinute--).

```
public static int getMinute(String timeString, Locale locale) {
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
                                                 .withLocale(locale);
  LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString, formatter);
  return time.getHour()*60 + time.getMinute();
}
```

Example:

```
System.out.println(getMinute("10.47", new Locale("fi")));   // 647
System.out.println(getMinute("11:23", Locale.ROOT));        // 683
```

---

If you don't care about the time separator, we could use a fixed pattern instead.

```
public static int getMinute(String timeString, Locale locale) {
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH[:][.]mm", locale);
  LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString, formatter);
  return time.getHour()*60 + time.getMinute();
}
```

(The `[…]` means optional, so it will match `HH:mm`, `HH.mm`, `HHmm` and `HH:.mm`)

Comment: There will be DateTimeParseException if locale is US, because timeString is in 'HH:mm" format and not 'HH:mm aa'

Comment: @Lega Well that means `HH:mm` is not the expected locale format for US. See update for an alternative.

Comment: `return time.getMinute();` will return only minute part of LocalTime, this should be rather `return time.getHour() * 60 + time.getMinute();` to return minutes from midnight

Answer (score 1):

Note very elegant, but it would do the job

```
String pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT)
    .withLocale(locale).format(LocalTime.MIN)
    .replaceFirst("\\d*", "H").replaceFirst("\\d.*", "mm");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern, locale);
int minutes = formatter.parse(string).get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getLocalizedDateTimePattern` method to get a pattern with which to initialise a `DateTimeFormatter`, to parse time with given locale. The first `null` is for the date that you don't need in your case.

```
String timePattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
            null, FormatStyle.SHORT, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
```

You then use it to create a formatter (note that you have to specify locale again):

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timePattern, locale);
```

If instead of the `SHORT` time format for the `locale` you expect `"HHcmm"` where `'c'` is a non numeric char that is the time separator for that `locale`, then either:

1. extract numbers from text

   ```
   String[] duration = durationString.split("\\D");
   int minutes = parseInt(duration[0])*60 + parseInt(duration[1]);
   ```
2. make a `DateTimeFormatter` with the time separator

   ```
   DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
           String.format("HH%smm", timeSeparator), locale);
   LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(text, dtf);
   int minutes = time.toSecondOfDay() / 60;
   ```

   or if you must

   ```
   int minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(LocalTime.MIN, time);
   ```

Comment: Here also will be DateTimeParseException if locale is US, because input is in 'HH:mm" format and not 'HH:mm aa'

Answer (score 0):

First parse the time to a `LocalTime` instance, afterwards calculate the difference to the start of the day using `Duration`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendLocalized(null, FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .toFormatter(Locale.ITALY);
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.from(formatter.parse("10.45"));
    long minutes = Duration.between(LocalTime.MIN, time).toMinutes();
```

above results to 645

Comment: Here also will be DateTimeParseException if locale is US, because input is in 'HH:mm" format and not 'HH:mm aa'